# Clear the input file-name on button click

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

Refer above image , how to clear "Koala.jpg" file name, each time when user hits a delete button , inside a bootstrap modal.

```js
$('#delImg').on({
  click: function() {
    $('#fileupload').attr("value", "");
    $('#fileupload').attr("src", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="box-body">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <div>
        <textarea id="" ng-model="" style="" class="textarea" placeholder="Post something"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <div id="imgdispy"></div>
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="delImg" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

The above code isn't working

After some google search , clearing cache can be the solution , but need help in understanding syntax and the real cause.

Comment: `$('#fileupload').val('')` ?

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rLpc7vmk/)**?

Comment: @vikrant checkout my answer its working, you can check snippet too

Comment: Tushar  , its working . Nice & Simple Syntax :)  +1

Comment: @GuruprasadRao your jsfiddle not working

Comment: It is working @Vikrant.. You **select a file** and then you click delete right?

Comment: yes , but unfortunately its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can replace file input with its clone ;

```
 $('body #exampleInputFile').replaceWith($('body #exampleInputFile').val('').clone(true));
```

**Here is the working code**

```js
$('#delImg').on('click', function() {
   // $('#fileupload').attr("value", "");
   // $('#fileupload').attr("src", "");
   
    $('body #exampleInputFile').replaceWith($('body #exampleInputFile').val('').clone(true));

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="box-body">
    <form method="post" action="#">
      <div>
        <textarea id="" ng-model="" style="" class="textarea" placeholder="Post something"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <div id="imgdispy"></div>
    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="delImg" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" data-dismiss="modal" role="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks working :)  ,  but  `$('#fileupload').val('')`   did my work

Comment: you have `exampleInputFile` in your sample code so i have let it same... accept if would like